# Not have tmux intercept a keystroke but pass it to the underlying vim instance

Tags: vim, tmux

I open vim from inside tmux and I would like particular keystroke sequences: <kbd>CTRL-F5</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-F6</kbd> passed onto the underlying vim instance and not intercepted by tmux. That is, these two keystroke sequences have been configured in my .vimrc

At present, these keystroke sequences seem to capitalize the word under the cursor due to tmux's interception of them and I do not want this behaviour.

On a related note, is it possible to check what a particular keystroke is mapped to do in tmux?

Comment: Do `<C-v>` then `<C-F5>` in your shell, then in a shell within tmux, then in Vim in your shell, and finally in Vim in tmux. What do you get?

Comment: This was resolved over at the github page for tmux. Turned out that this had to do with my wrongly setting TERM in .bashrc. That thread is [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3453)

Comment: @romainl Yes, I tried these and did some probing with the help of the maintainer of tmux. It has gotten resolved. Thanks!